# gmail smtp with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am trying to get a confirmation email sending using a gmail account. I have looked around and there is nothing that is obvious. There is no errors or anything, it just dosn't send

I have this as the initalizer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true


ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "<address>@gmail.com",
  :password             => "<password>",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

Comment: what is your console output when sending email?

Answer (score 65):

You don't need `tlsmail` gem anymore at least with Rails 3.2

This will be sufficient

```ruby
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
  :user_name            => '<username>',
  :password             => '<password>',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

From the all-mighty-guide [ActionMailer configuration for gmail](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail)

Comment: Awesome, nice to know. Saving me a bunch of headaches. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: No problem ;) I now got used to search in the Rails guides almost everything

Comment: Apparently, `:domain` is [optional](http://bit.ly/QAAPPv), though you wouldn't know that from reading the [docs](http://am.rubyonrails.org/).

Answer (score 8):

add tlsmail to gemfile

```
gem 'tlsmail'
```

run :

```
bundle install
```

add these settings to config/envirnoments/development.rb file

```
YourApplicationName::Application.configure do
    require 'tlsmail'
      Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
      ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
      ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
      ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
      ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
          :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
          :port => "587",
          :domain => "gmail.com",
          :enable_starttls_auto => true,
          :authentication => :login,
          :user_name => "<addreee>@gmail.com",
          :password => "<password>"
      }

    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: don't forget to restart server ;)

Answer (score 5):

You should check that **my_user_name@gmail.com** has actually sent the email. We have had issues with this in the past when sending verification emails out through Gmail's SMTP server, since sending in bulk end up not sending at all.

I suggest you log into my_user_name@gmail.com and verify that there are no problems and that the emails are sent.

If not, you may want try a service like [Send Grid](http://sendgrid.com/) to send outgoing emails.

Alternatively, you can look into your server. Or if you are in development, have a look at `log/development.log`. I'm pretty sure that you can see in your logs that it's actually trying to send the mail.

The problem is that Google doesn't trust your local IP address and your mails won't get delivered (not even to the spam directory). There is no way to work around this but using a white-listed server.

You can try this out by deploying your app into a production server like Heroku and test it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
  :user_name            => '<username>',
  :password             => '<password>',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

The `<username>` means to fill in your real username? So does the `<password>`