# Send email with devise Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

Are these two lines equivalent:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings ={
```

I'm trying to configure devise to send emails and have been looking at multiple guides.  Some seem to use the top line, while others use the bottom.

I'm on rails 3.2.  Is one of these new to 3.2?

Thanks

Comment: I use the bottom line and have used it since rails 3.0, don't know about the top one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send email then use this guide. Both lines are Equivalent.

[gmail smtp with rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379950/gmail-smtp-with-rails-3/6382667#6382667)