# ActionMailer and Gmails setup Rails 3.0.1/3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I've been trying to set up ActionMailer with my rails app without success. I have searched several different threads without finding a solution. Is there a gem of some sort that I need to install to prevent my issue?

Here is the issue:

https://gist.github.com/3341261

==Solution==

So my solution was to go to use tlsmail gem. I followed this thread and the second answer there helped me solve my issue.

[gmail smtp with rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379950/gmail-smtp-with-rails-3)

There is a gotcha when it comes to unicorn. I was using an init.d file to restart my server, however I had to actually stop the server then remove the pid file manually for unicorn. After starting unicorn it worked.

Comment: 3.0.10 is the version of rails.

Comment: What is your Ruby version? Ruby 1.8.6 does not have starttls. Long shot.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Hm, think you should try as Amar suggested, a tlsmail gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution was to go to use tlsmail gem. I followed this thread and the second answer there helped me solve my issue.

gmail smtp with rails 3

There is a gotcha when it comes to unicorn. I was using an init.d file to restart my server, however I had to actually stop the server then remove the pid file manually for unicorn. After starting unicorn it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The below is one of my settings that worked. Hope it might help you spot something awry.  =)

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :port                 => 587,
        :domain               => 'mobileme.com',
        :user_name            => 'hello@mobileme.com',
        :password             => 'Z!DDq%a!OsfGCsdsd2mEc',
        :authentication       => 'plain',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true  
    }
```

Of course the I change the domain and password.

Comment: Here are my settings which are not working at the moment... Same error with "starttls must issue first.."

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { 
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com", 
  :port                 => 587, 
  :domain               => "domain.com", 
  :user_name            => "bot", 
  :password             => 'passwordF', 
  :authentication       => "plain", 
  :enable_starttls_auto => true 
}

Answer (score 0):

Try
`:enable_starttls_auto => true` option in action mailer configuration

Comment: I have tried to enable this and still get the same error mentioned above.

Comment: I've installed tlsmail gem via this answer, but I'm getting an error saying it cannot find the file... odd has a 7 by it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379950/gmail-smtp-with-rails-3

When I run bundle list it shows up...

Comment: Update... I ran this using rails server webbrick and it appears to work, however when I try to start it up with unicorn it can not load in the gem.