# Email sent from Rails + Postfix goes to spam folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, postfix-mta

I send email from my domain using postfix without any issue. The problem is that when I send same email using a Rails application with same sender address, the message goes to spam folder in Gmail.
I've tested it with and without Message-ID option in the mailer class:

```
default "Message-ID" => "#{Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(Time.now.to_i.to_s)}@mydomail.com"
```

This is my SMTP configurations:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:                 "127.0.0.1",
    port:                    25,
    enable_starttls_auto:    false
}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

What configuration option I've missed that caused my emails to go to the spam folder?

Comment: Could you include all the ActionMailer configuration you have done? Do you think that following this configurations would help as nobody there experienced this problem? Why are you using port 25 instead of 587? Why did you disable tls auto? Are you sending email with black carbon copies? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379950/gmail-smtp-with-rails-3#10795856

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio: That was all the ActionMailer configuration that I did plus `config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false`. I don't have any idea what is the difference between port 25 and 587 and why I set auto tls to true. Is it possible that this is the cause of spamming outgoing messages?

Comment: how is the `config.mailer_sender = 'noreply@truhawk.com'` in devise.rb, `default_url_options`, did you set content type in your environment.rb `ActionMailer::Base.default_content_type = "text/html"`?  I am attaching you some links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186584/how-do-i-set-up-email-confirmation-with-devise 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186584/how-do-i-set-up-email-confirmation-with-devise

Comment: Problem solved. That was an issue by Postfix and SPF record in DNS. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a Postfix + DNS problem. Emails goes to spam folder in Gmail that means everything is ok with Rails. After I checked the Postfix `main.cf` noticed that the `host` value was `srv1.example.com` and SPF record in DNS was `example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly standard these days. Spammers can easily set up local SMTP servers to send out millions of emails a day much more easily and cheaply than buying dedicated IP addresses to send these emails from.

As a result, quite often emails sent from localhost will end up in spam by default.

You can overcome this fairly easily by using something like SendGrid, MailGun or Amazon SES.

Comment: I have a static IP address and the application is running in production environment on the server.